# MySQL replication not synced

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave-replication

I set up a replica between two MySQL servers. After my initial setup, the replication worked without any problem, but now they are out of sync.

On **Master** I can see:

```
Variable    Valor
File    mysql-bin.000200
Position    93069547
Binlog_Do_DB    
Binlog_Ignore_DB
```

And:

```
ID del servidor Servidor
1670759689
```

On the **Slave**:

```
Variable    Valor
Slave_IO_State  Queueing source event to the relay log
Master_Host IP_ADDRESS_FROM_MY_MASTER
Master_User c44b0fbab37cf3
Master_Port 3306
Connect_Retry   60
Master_Log_File mysql-bin.000006
Read_Master_Log_Pos 8759143
Relay_Log_File  ns328448-relay-bin.000003
Relay_Log_Pos   67837
Relay_Master_Log_File   mysql-bin.000006
Slave_IO_Running    Yes
Slave_SQL_Running   Yes
Replicate_Do_DB 
Replicate_Ignore_DB 
Replicate_Do_Table  
Replicate_Ignore_Table  
Replicate_Wild_Do_Table 
Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table 
Last_Errno  0
Last_Error  
Skip_Counter    0
Exec_Master_Log_Pos 67621
Relay_Log_Space 8759800
Until_Condition None
Until_Log_File  
Until_Log_Pos   0
Master_SSL_Allowed  No
Master_SSL_CA_File  
Master_SSL_CA_Path  
Master_SSL_Cert 
Master_SSL_Cipher   
Master_SSL_Key  
Seconds_Behind_Master   2606688
```

After a reboot on the slave, it seems the server is catching up with the pending files.

1. What can be done to prevent this "out of sync" to happen?
2. How can I investigate what caused the system to get stucked?
3. I see all the log files are stored on the server, how can I set a max number of files to be kept?

Thanks,
Javi

**-- EDIT --**

Today the status for servers are:
**Master**

```
Variable    Valor
File    mysql-bin.000209
Position    61419650
...
```

**Slave**

```
Variable    Valor
Slave_IO_State  Waiting for source to send event
...
Master_Log_File mysql-bin.000209
Read_Master_Log_Pos 62149115
Relay_Log_File  ns328448-relay-bin.000016
Relay_Log_Pos   42109202
Relay_Master_Log_File   mysql-bin.000011
Slave_IO_Running    Yes
Slave_SQL_Running   Yes
...
Exec_Master_Log_Pos 42108986
Relay_Log_Space 19138941381
...
Seconds_Behind_Master   2528578
```

It catch my attention that in both cases, "Master_Log_File" points to the same file and "Read_Master_Log_Pos" (almost) to the same position.

"Seconds_Behind_Master" has not changed much.

If I restart the Slave server, and check its status again, it has "magically" changed to:

```
Slave_IO_State  Queueing source event to the relay log
...
Master_Log_File mysql-bin.000008
Read_Master_Log_Pos 3812616
Relay_Log_File  ns328448-relay-bin.000003
Relay_Log_Pos   6100
Relay_Master_Log_File   mysql-bin.000008
Slave_IO_Running    Yes
Slave_SQL_Running   Yes
...
Exec_Master_Log_Pos 5884
Relay_Log_Space 3813225
...
Seconds_Behind_Master   2626954
```

And now "Master_Log_File" and "Read_Master_Log_Pos" point to a different place.

Does this help?

Comment: *but now they are out of sync*, what caused the out of sync? 2.6M seconds it's a long time and it can't occurred  due to heavy writings on the master

Comment: Do any clients run DDL or locking queries on the replica? They could be blocking replication from executing. So the replication threads count as "Running" but they are just waiting.

Comment: Your question about log files is unclear. Which server do you mean, the source or the replica? On the replica, relay logs are removed immediately once they are executed. You might have many relay logs, but that's natural if your SBM is 2.6M seconds.

Comment: @ErgestBasha, I do not know what was the root cause of the issue. I set the slave to ignore the errors, as it is not critical if they are not exactly the same. What can be consider "heavy writing"? In the worst case, there might be just 200 writes per second on the master.

Comment: @BillKarwin, as far as I know there are not DLL or Locking queries.... Is there a way to check that configuration / action? Regarding the log files, on my master, it stores all the bin files, and that is taking few GB of data. Is that the regular approach, or is it worth do something to delete the bin files that has been synced and only keep the last X bin files?

Comment: There are options to purge binary log files automatically by time, not by the number of log files. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days or if you use MySQL 8.0 use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_expire_logs_seconds

Comment: You should know if you have queries running on your replica instance. You can view what is currently running in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` (make sure you run this while connected to the replica, not the source, because it only shows the threads on the instance you're connected to).

Comment: Try `SLAVE STOP; SLAVE START;` if it happens again.  (This won't determine the cause, but _may_ get you going quicker.)

Comment: Is the Replica a slower machine?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%expire%';` -- That controls when the binlogs (on Primary) are being deleted.  If that is less than 2606688 seconds, you have already lost some files.  Do not delete any binlogs manually, at least not until the SBM is solved.

Comment: @RickJames, both machines have the same SW and HW